# Should a list of employees be sorted alphabetically by first name?

Tags: grid, sorting

Imagine a list or grid of employees, assuming the non-technical user hasn't clicked any column headers yet, do you think they would expect the employees to be sorted by first name or last name or the order they were added to the system, i.e. oldest employee first, newest last.

In addition if they added a new employee should that appear at the end or slotted in alphabetically?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that is not alphabetical order will make the user think about what the order is. If you order by new employee how long will it take for them to learn what the order is ?

Comment: This is what I though, just wanted someone else to verify it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is a grid, then you have the additional problem of working out how the individual grids are sorted top to bottom or left to right (i.e. which way first). There are similar questions on [sorting in a grid or tile design pattern](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/66412/design-pattern-for-sorting-ordering-items-in-card-view/69662#69662) you can reference.

For a list, generally if it is in a tabular format or style then you would expect the sorting scheme to be defined (by either the top/header row or some other indication). There are different conventions on the default sorting strategy but as long as it is clearly indicated then I don't think you'll have any issues.

The best thing is to allow some flexibility in the search somewhere, especially if it is a really long list. Alternatively you can provide some form of filtering to narrow down the amount of scrolling or scanning the user needs to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll ensure it is clearly marked and a search function is now on my 'to do' list.